# Can you join a table with another table you are pivoting on a field you are creating with the pivot?

Tags: mysql, join, pivot

I have a table I need to pivot that contains a value I need to join with a field in another table. I'm trying to determine if I can do this in one step, or if I need to pivot the first table and then join them together. **GROUP_ID** is in field_name in the redcap_data table and needs to be joined with group_id in redcap_data_access_groups.

```
CREATE VIEW vwGlobalHealthInfants AS
SELECT rd.record as record_id,
MAX(CASE WHEN rd.field_name = '__GROUP_ID__' THEN rd.value ELSE NULL END) as GroupId,
g.group_name as hospno,
MAX(CASE WHEN rd.field_name = 'admission_temperature' THEN rd.value ELSE NULL END) as adtemp,
MAX(CASE WHEN rd.field_name = 'antenatal_care' THEN rd.value ELSE NULL END) as antecare,
MAX(CASE WHEN rd.field_name = 'anti_hypertensive' THEN rd.value ELSE NULL END) as antihyper,
MAX(CASE WHEN rd.field_name = 'anticonvulsants' THEN rd.value ELSE NULL END) as anticonvul
FROM (
redcapVON.redcap_data rd
JOIN redcapVON.redcap_data_access_groups g ON ( (
GroupId = g.group_id
) )
)
WHERE (
rd.project_id = 12
)
GROUP BY rd.record
```

I don't know if it's possible to get it to recognize the GroupID field in the join before the pivot.

Comment: you can use Common Table Expressions (sometimes referred to as WITH queries). and in one query it can done

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

CTE would solve it. We just don't have the most updated version of mysql to run it. 2 steps it is.